# evict specific transitive dependency in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

Suppose a small test project (sbt 0.13.8, full project as [gist](https://gist.github.com/wookietreiber/b8306d282f8b9151dc11)):

```
name := "test"

organization := "org.example"

version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
  "com.lowagie"              %  "itext"         % "4.2.1",
  "com.github.wookietreiber" %% "scala-chart"   % "0.4.2"
)
```

The dependency tree looks as follows:

```
dependencyTree
[info] org.example:test_2.11:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT [S]
[info]   +-com.github.wookietreiber:scala-chart_2.11:0.4.2 [S]
[info]   | +-org.jfree:jfreechart:1.0.17
[info]   | | +-org.jfree:jcommon:1.0.21
[info]   | | +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
[info]   | | 
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-swing_2.11:1.0.1 [S]
[info]   | 
[info]   +-com.lowagie:itext:4.2.1
[info]     +-bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:138
[info]     | +-org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:1.38
[info]     |   +-org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:1.38
[info]     |   | +-org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.38
[info]     |   | 
[info]     |   +-org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:1.38
[info]     |   
[info]     +-dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
[info]     | +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2 (evicted by: 1.3.04)
[info]     | +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
[info]     | 
[info]     +-jfree:jfreechart:1.0.12
[info]     | +-jfree:jcommon:1.0.15
[info]     | 
[info]     +-org.swinglabs:pdf-renderer:1.0.5
[info]     
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jun 2, 2015 12:16:14 PM
```

The problem is the dependency `jfreechart` which gets pulled in by both `scala-chart` as well as by `itext` (same goes for `jcommon`, but I will focus on `jfreechart`). However, the slightly older version that gets pulled in by `itext` uses another organization name (`jfree` vs. `org.jfree`).

Normally, if those would use the same organization, the older one would get evicted (as is done in the example with `xml-apis`) and there would be no conflicts as long as there is binary compatibility.

The real conflict now is that both dependencies `jfree:jfreechart` and `org.jfree:jfreechart` are both on the classpath and provide the same classes. Compilation works fine and sbt does not even complain. Take e.g. the following example `App`:

```
package org.example

import scalax.chart.api._

object Main extends App {
  val data = for {
    i <- 1 to 5
    category = i.toString
    date = new org.jfree.data.time.Day(i, 2, 1998)
    value = i * 2
  } yield category -> Map(date -> value)

  val chart = XYAreaChart.stacked(data.toTimeTable)

  chart.saveAsPDF("/tmp/my-chart.pdf")
}
```

This compiles just fine! I don't know how sbt chooses which dependency to use. It all blows up if you try to actually run the thing:

```
sbt @ test $ compile
[info] Updating {file:/home/wookietreiber/projects/scala/jfree-itext-test/}jfree-itext-test...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /tmp/sbt/test/scala-2.11/classes...
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jun 2, 2015 1:18:36 PM
sbt @ test $ run
[info] Running org.example.Main 
[error] (run-main-1) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jfree.data.time.TimeTableXYDataset.add(Lorg/jfree/data/time/TimePeriod;Ljava/lang/Number;Ljava/lang/Comparable;Z)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jfree.data.time.TimeTableXYDataset.add(Lorg/jfree/data/time/TimePeriod;Ljava/lang/Number;Ljava/lang/Comparable;Z)V
        at scalax.chart.module.RichChartingCollections$RichCategorizedTuple2s$$anonfun$toTimeTable$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(RichChartingCollections.scala:300)
...
```

To solve this, I would need to specifically evict / remove the older `jfree:jfreechart` and `jfree:jcommon` versions from the dependency list / classpath. Is this possible and if so how?

---

Another issue I discovered is with `sbt-assembly` with errors like the following (for each duplicate file):

```
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/wookietreiber/.ivy2/cache/jfree/jfreechart/jars/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar:org/jfree/data/KeyedValues2D.class
[error] /home/wookietreiber/.ivy2/cache/org.jfree/jfreechart/jars/jfreechart-1.0.17.jar:org/jfree/data/KeyedValues2D.class
```

Comment: I just recreated the other situation where it blows up: I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` because sbt is in fact using the older version of `jfree:jfreechart` for compilation that is missing a method that is there in `org.jfree:jfreechart` which gets included with `scala-chart`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define `mergeStragey in assembly` either in your *.sbt or *.scala project definition to work with the sbt-assembly command. Below is a sample.

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
  {
    case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "codahale", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "yammer", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
    case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
    case x => old(x)
  }
}
```

If you have a clear idea what the transitive jar that causes problem, you can exclude it in your libraryDependencies. For example, I excluded the httpclient jar from my direct dependency on play 2.3.6 which depends a higher version of httpclient which is not what I desired.

```
 "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.3.6" exclude("org.apache.httpcomponents", "httpclient")
```

In your case, you can do `exclude("jfree", "jfreechart")` to your direct dependency that introduced this old jar.

Comment: Thanks, this certainly help with the `sbt-assembly`-related issue, however, not with the more general one. Do you have ideas on that?

Comment: What is your general question?

Comment: how to evict this specific dependency globally in sbt,  not just for sbt-assembly